# How to permanently delete this line in Kernel IP Routing table

Tags: raspbian, networking, kernel, sudo

I have a problem to delete line in next routing table.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         160.99.37.11    0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
160.99.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
```

I use command:
"sudo route del -net 160.99.0.0/16", this command is ok and is working.

When i reboot RPi there is a problem, the line draws back.
How to permanently delete this line?

My version Linux:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID_LIKE=debian


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
GNU nano 2.2.6         File: /etc/network/interfaces

iface eth0 inet manual
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
   allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

/etc/network/interfaces - after changes 15.10.2016

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual
   up route add -net 160.99.40.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 160.99.37.11

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46737/discussion-on-question-by-dimitrije-mita-dimitrijevic-how-to-permanently-delete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the following original routing table,

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         160.99.37.11    0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
160.99.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
```

(Don't need to say that any 160.99.37.XXX or 160.99.40.XXX address is in the 160.99.0.0/16 subnet.)

your raspi (which has 160.99.37.XXX IP address) tries to access any address in the 160.99.0.0/16 subnet by broadcasting, not by using the default routing rule.

your raspi accesses any address not in the 160.99.0.0/16 subnet through the gateway 160.99.37.11 defined in the default routing rule.

When the specified routing rule is deleted, your raspi has the following routing table.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         160.99.37.11    0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
```

In this case, your raspi accesses any address (not only 160.99.37.XXX or 160.99.40.XXX) through the gateway 160.99.37.11 which is capable of communicating with destination addresses.

From this picture, what I don't understand is that

- If you (I mean the IP of your raspi) are permitted to access the 160.99.40.0/24 subnet, why not a routing rule for this purpose is configured in your network.
- For this case, I think the routing policies of your network are not configured properly.

OR

- If you are not permitted to access the 160.99.40.0/24 subnet, how you are able to access the 160.99.40.0/24 subnet through the gateway 160.99.37.11.
- For this case, I think the security policies of your network are not configured properly.

**As conclusion,**

1. There is no limitation on your network to access the 160.99.40.0/24 subnet from your raspi
2. There is no proper routing configuration on your network to access the 160.99.40.0/24 subnet from your raspi

**As solution,**

1. **Do not delete** the specified routing rule on your raspi, because you can break some other things about your raspi's network configuration
2. Instead, define a new routing rule

**UPDATE #1** For Raspbian Jessie, static routes are set by `hook files` placed under `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/` directory.

- by adding `up route add -net 160.99.40.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 160.99.37.11`
- after the line `iface eth0 inet manual`
- in `/etc/network/interfaces` file
- by creating a file `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/40-WhateverFilenameYouChoose`
- which includes routing rules like `ip route add 160.99.40.0/24 via 160.99.37.11`

Your final routing table will look like this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         160.99.37.11    0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
160.99.40.0     160.99.37.11    255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
160.99.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Dear sir, thank you so much for very good explanation. I set up command in /etc/network/interfaces, but it still doesn't remember the route when you restart it. I am the only administrator user. What is the problem?

Comment: Please post the output of route command with your new configuration.

Comment: #interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
#Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
#For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'
#Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual
   up route add -net 160.99.40.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 160.99.37.11
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: Image:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/86wlzb2hvqpyh32/2016-10-14_2056.png?dl=0

Comment: Link for image:  https://we.tl/dpnIaseoVW

Comment: Please use the text editor in the way it is supposed to be used, otherwise no one will be able to help.

Comment: Please find above the changes in the text editor. It is my first visit to the forum so thank you for the advice.

Comment: Have you ever make it working with new route configuration? Test it without appending to interfaces file, just by adding manually from command line i.e. `route add ...`

Comment: Yes it works that way, but it forgets the command when it is restarted.

Comment: The answer is updated.

Comment: Can i make cronjob in crontab, when it reboots script.sh starts ?
@reboot sudo

Comment: Just read the updated answer. It kills all your pain. It makes the route permanent.